# Export Data Extension to FTP server via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, c#

Looking for a faster solution to download data extension data.  Currently we have a solution similar to this ...

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension/

The number of rows we are downloading has increased significantly so we are looking for a faster solution.

As the above page states, performance can be increased by delivering the data to an Enhanced FTP Location.

It links to this page...
https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api/

...however I am not sure what parameters need to be specified for the ExtractRequest to return the Data Extension rows?

So if anyone could outline this process and the parameters needed that would be a huge help.

Comment: How often are you looking to get the data?

Comment: Frequency can vary from daily to weekly.  Which raises another question, following the first down load is it possible to return only persisted rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This url has been updated with an example of how to export/extract a DE to the related "Enhanced FTP Export Directory", near the bottom of the page titled "[How to Create a Data Extention Data Extract](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api/)".

### update for 2018...

See the following link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api.htm

If using an Extract Request to get data from a DE, ensure that the extract ID = bb94a04d-9632-4623-be47-daabc3f588a6, use the DECustomerKey parameter to specify the DE and include all other required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend set this up within the ET application itself. It would be much easier than doing it in the API.  What you would do:

1. Set up a query activity to grab the persisted data and put it in a new data extension (using overwrite, so you can reuse it)
2. Set up an data extract activity to extract the data.
3. Set up a file transfer activity to moved the extract to the FTP server.
4. Set up an automation in Automation Studio to do these steps in order.  This will allow you schedule the frequency.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do like your approach to gather the persisted data, however I need the entire routine done through the API.

Comment: Could you please share your use case?  The only case I can possibly see is that you need to change the steps dynamically. And you would still be able to do that part dynamically.  I've done it both ways, and I obviously prefer the one I have in my answer, so I'd like to know.  Thanks!

Comment: It is just not appropriate for us to use the Exact Target UI to automate this process for customers.  Have you setup a data extract for a Data Extension via the API?

Comment: Fair enough.  Have a look at http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding completely, but can't you set up the automation and use the API to run the automation via your chosen input?  https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api/